# bug in highcharts histogram regarding number of bins

Tags: highcharts, histogram

highcharts histogram number of bins works only with workaround using baseSeries, not with data directly, any suggestions?

```
var data = [3.5, 3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4, 2.9, 3.1, 3.7, 3]
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Histogram'
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Histogram',
        type: 'histogram',
        baseSeries: 's1',
        // data: data,
        binsNumber: 10
    }, {
        name: 'Data',
        type: 'scatter',
        data: data,
        id: 's1',
        visible: false
    }]
});
```

good:

https://jsfiddle.net/erez_ahar/u0mebqzg/10/

not good:

https://jsfiddle.net/erez_ahar/u0mebqzg/11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a bug. As you can find in the documentation:

> The histogram series is a column series with no padding between the columns and with self-setting data. Unlike most other Highcharts series, the data property is not available - it is set internally based on the base series data (more precisely y values of the data).

More about the histogram - [documentation](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/histogram-series)

So everything works as it should be.

Comment: Thanks @sebastian-wędzel. Almost fully correct, the data property available https://jsfiddle.net/erez_ahar/u0mebqzg/13/

Comment: @Erez What do you have in mind? The histogram calculates a column values basic on some range of data from other series.

Comment: Like in python/matlab, histogram of its own series